# First time working with Word2Vec, try to cluster users based on their skill set

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, cluster-analysis, word2vec

For my thesis I have to analyse the skill of candidates. I have to cluster the users and compare their skillsets. The information is classified so I made a random database which have the same structure so I can show how my data is build.

```
import random
listOfSkills = ["Dutch","Java OSGI","XML Transformation Query","Java Enterprise Edition","Functional Design","Scrum","Python","JavaScript","Ruby","Java","SQL","Data Analytics","Machine Learning","Deep Learning","English"]

rand_item = random.choice(listOfSkills)

n = 5

rand_items = random.sample(listOfSkills, n)

test_skillset = []

for i in range(5):
    result = random.sample(listOfSkills, n)
    string = ", ".join(result)
    test_skillset.append(string)

test_id_ = np.arange(0, len(test_skillset)).tolist()

test_dict = {'id' : test_id_,
             'skillset' : test_skillset
             }

test_df = pd.DataFrame(test_dict)
```

After running this code I get a DataFrame which looks like this:

```
id, skillset
0, "Java, ruby, ..."
1, "Java, ruby, ..."
2, "Java, ruby, ..."
```

This is the same for the database I got.

The list of skills are some of the skills I found in the database. Also there are more users in the database which also have more skills.

I am quite new to machine learning and to using Word2Vec models. I tried some stuff but almost all the time I don't get a result which gives me extra information. Some of the skills have a long name which maybe messes up the model. Or I did something wrong.

One of my goals is to cluster the users and find similarities between each skill set.

My final goal is to match the vectors of the skill set with vacancies to check how good of a match a user can be with an open vacancy. But first I need to know if I can find similarities between the users.

So my question are:

- How can I use Word2Vec to find individual similarities between skills?
- How can I use Word2Vec cluster the users to find similar skillsets?

Sorry if my question is a bit vague, English isn't my native language and Python is a bit new to me.
I am open to clarify things if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Word2vec was originally unveiled as an algorithm trained on long, real natural language texts, which include many subtly-varied examples of word usage, in original contexts.

You seem to be applying it to a smaller controlled-vocabulary of known-skills, using training-data that isn't full natural language communication – just lists.

Word2vec & similar algorithms can sometimes offer interesting results on such not-quite-real-language corpora, but can require more tinkering with the training data, and parameters further from the usual defaults for natural language texts, for better results.

In particular, if you are using a randomly-generated corpus – especially one generated by uniform sampling from a tiny list of just 15 'words'! – you shouldn't expect the word2vec algorithm to do anything useful. There's no language-like pattern of relative word-meanings in such an artificial corpus. (And, any tiny hints-of-correlation any one run might show would be noise from your random sample, totally unlike the gradations of meaning real languages have, and real training texts would show.)

(There are probably other errors, as well, in your "tried some stuff" experiments that didn't yield useful results – but this use of a random training set is just the most obvious problem, in what you've shown.)

To get useful "skills vectors" you'll need lots of realistic data, and to adjust things like the size/options of your training to match the limits of what you have. (As just one example, it's nonsensical to try to train even 20-dimensional 'dense embedding' vectors, like those from word2vec, for a vocabulary that's less than 20 tokens long – & you'd probably need 400+ unique tokens to make 20-dimensional vectors start making sense.)

With the right data, you should start to see meaningful relationships between such skills-vectors – with related skills nearer each other than unrelated skills, and even the directions-of-differences suggestive of certain human-describable aspects of skills (like "more enterprisey", or "more abstract mathy"). But you can't even really eyeball those results for sanity/improvement unless it's realistic data, with real relationships, which you can evaluate using your domain knowledge.

You might then be able to try alternate ways of composing those into per-candidate summaries (such as averaging the skills-vectors together), or just use some composite measure-of-distance which relies on word-vectors (like say "Word Mover's Distance"), in order to try candidate-level clustering.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I looked at my data set and there are around 1061 unique skills, with a total amount of almost 5000 skills divided by 200 users. Do you think this is enough to work with. The list of skills in the dummy database was just to show how the database looks like. So in that case the example I gave was maybe not that representative.

Comment: That's really tiny for training a data-hungry algorithm like word2vec... but the only way to know is to try. Just beware you'll not be able to do typical 100-300 dimensional vectors for such a small vocabulary, and if each user has an average of 25 skills, when you create your fake 'sentences' results avoid creating fake relationships with arbitrary choices about token-ordering. (For example, listing skills in alphabetical order, or any stable order, with a small `window`, could create spurious close relationships between skills that you happen to list near each other.)